# How to create dummy variables using various columns sharing same levels

Tags: r, linear-regression, dummy-variable

I am trying to get the dummy variables for the following table:

```
df:

Value1       var1       var2      var3      var4
9.330154398  HomeATL    AwayHOU   HomeEast  AwayWest
32.43881489  AwaySDN    HomeATL   HomeWest  AwayWest
54.77178387  AwayLAN    HomeATL   AwayEast  HomeSame
54.77178387  AwayLAN    HomeATL   AwayWest  HomeEast
```

The column `var1` and `var2` share the same levels. On the other hand, the column `var3` and `var4` whare their levels as well. Therefore, I need that during the creation of the dummy variables, the new columns created should not have repeated levels. I mean, in the example of var3 and var4, for the 1st and 3rd row, both have `AwayWest`, so I only need to fill 1 column named `AwayWest` with a number 1 on each row.

My desired output is:

```
Value1  HomeEast    HomeWest    AwayEast    AwayWest    HomeSame    HomeATL AwayHOU AwaySDN AwayLAN
9.330154398 1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0
32.43881489 0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0
54.77178387 0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   1
54.77178387 1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1
```

I tried creating a new column of 1 (`col1`) for each column to be transformed:

```
spread(df,var1, col1) %>%
spread(var2, col1)%>%
spread(var3, col1)%>%
spread(var1, col1)
```

However it is not working.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify categories to be considered in dummy variables when doing linear model in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56121867/how-to-modify-categories-to-be-considered-in-dummy-variables-when-doing-linear-m)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `base R` option would be `table`

```
tbl <- +(table(c(col(df1[-1])), unlist(df1[-1]) ) > 0)
cbind(df1[1], as.data.frame.matrix(tbl))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
rownames_to_column(df1, 'rn') %>%
    gather(key, val, var1:var4) %>% 
    count(rn, val) %>%
    spread(val, n, fill = 0)  %>%
    select(-rn) %>%
    bind_cols(df1[1], .)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Value1 = c(9.330154398, 32.43881489, 54.77178387, 
54.77178387), var1 = c("HomeATL", "AwaySDN", "AwayLAN", "AwayLAN"
), var2 = c("AwayHOU", "HomeATL", "HomeATL", "HomeATL"), var3 = c("HomeEast", 
"HomeWest", "AwayEast", "AwayWest"), var4 = c("AwayWest", "AwayWest", 
"HomeSame", "HomeEast")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Hi. What happens if I have more than one column in my dataset, and the columns var1,2,3,4 are in somewhere inside the dataframe. May I use something similar?

Comment: @ManuelVillamil  If you know the index of columns, it is easier `unlist(df1[c(2, 5, 7, 14)])`  or if there is a pattern for column names `nm1 <- grep("var\\d+", names(df1))` and use that to subset the data

Comment: I liked the tidyverse option. Thanks it worked. I have one more question. What happens if I want to add a specific value instead of 1 or 0. I mean, I have a column with the value which the dummy variable of var3 should account.  What should I modify from your approach?? This would be the dataset :

Comment: `df1 <- structure(list(Value1 = c(9.330154398, 32.43881489, 54.77178387, 54.77178387),
                      var1 = c("HomeATL", "AwaySDN", "AwayLAN", "AwayLAN"),
                      var2 = c("AwayHOU", "HomeATL", "HomeATL", "HomeATL"),
                      var3 = c("HomeEast", "HomeWest", "AwayEast", "AwayWest"),
                      var3values = c(1,2,3,4),
                      var4 = c("AwayWest", "AwayWest", "HomeSame", "HomeEast"),
                      var4values = c(5,6,7,8)), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-4L))`

Comment: @ManuelVillamil What about for for 'var1' and 'var2'

Comment: @ManuelVillamil  You may try `rownames_to_column(df1, 'rn') %>%gather(key, val, matches("^var\\d+$")) %>% group_by(rn, val) %>% mutate(n = case_when(key == "var3" ~ var3values, key == "var4" ~ var4values, TRUE ~ as.numeric(n()))) %>% select(-var3values, -var4values, -key) %>% spread(val, n, fill = 0) %>%  ungroup %>% select(-rn)`

Answer (score 3):

A base R option would be to use `model.matrix`

```
df <- cbind(df[, "Value1", drop = F], model.matrix(Value1 ~ . - 1, data = df))
df
#     Value1 var1AwayLAN var1AwaySDN var1HomeATL var2HomeATL var3AwayWest
#1  9.330154           0           0           1           0            0
#2 32.438815           0           1           0           1            0
#3 54.771784           1           0           0           1            0
#4 54.771784           1           0           0           1            1
#  var3HomeEast var3HomeWest var4HomeEast var4HomeSame
#1            1            0            0            0
#2            0            1            0            0
#3            0            0            0            1
#4            0            0            1            0
```

If necessary, we can fix the column names with

```
names(df) <- sub("var\\d", "", names(df))
```

to reproduce your expected output.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Value1       var1       var2      var3      var4
9.330154398  HomeATL    AwayHOU   HomeEast  AwayWest
32.43881489  AwaySDN    HomeATL   HomeWest  AwayWest
54.77178387  AwayLAN    HomeATL   AwayEast  HomeSame
54.77178387  AwayLAN    HomeATL   AwayWest  HomeEast", header = T)
```

Comment: Thanks. May I ask you one more thing. My current dataset has more variables, I mean, I just created this example with one but it has about 45 other variables. Should I write each one by one as you wrote Value1???

Comment: @ManuelVillamil Best to isolate the variable columns from `model.matrix`; then `cbind` the variable columns and dummy-coded design matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this-

```
   > data.table::setDT(df)[,id:=1:.N]
   > cbind(df[,.(Value1)],dcast(
      melt(setDT(df)[, c(.(id=id), lapply(c("var1","var2","var3","var4"), function(x) paste0(x, get(x))))], id.vars="id"),
      id ~ value,
      length))
```

Output-

```
     Value1  id var1AwayLAN var1AwaySDN var1HomeATL var2AwayHOU var2HomeATL var3AwayEast var3AwayWest var3HomeEast var3HomeWest
1:  9.330154  1           0           0           1           1           0            0            0            1            0
2: 32.438815  2           0           1           0           0           1            0            0            0            1
3: 54.771784  3           1           0           0           0           1            1            0            0            0
4: 54.771784  4           1           0           0           0           1            0            1            0            0
```